# Как из php вытащить определенное значение

Tags: php

```
<?php the_listing_categories(); ?>
```

В такой штуке хранится адрес организации в таком формате

> Город, Район, ул. название-улицы, 14

подскажите знающие люди как из этого вывести только город и район
может это можно сделать с помощью php функции допустим substr

Comment: `<?php $arr = explode(',', the_listing_categories()); echo $arr[0].' - '.$arr[1]; ?>`  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я сделал прям как вы написали но все что изменилось в конце добавилось "-" может нужно еще что нибудь написать?

Comment: Значит что-то вы не досказали)) Или например  в  `the_listing_categories` у вас нет `return` .... ибо https://ideone.com/xZjMjz

Comment: @АлексейШиманский помогите пожалуйста если этого return нет то как еще можно сделать?

Comment: А как вы получаете данные `Город, Район, ул. название-улицы, 14`, если функция ничего не возвращает?.......... Нужен полный ваш код php......включая функцию `the_listing_categories` что она там делает......ибо непонятно как вы тогда сами данные получаете, чтобы ими манипулировать......... отредактируйте вопрос, добавив нужную информацию